# Function for Replace And Strip

Tags: python, ironpython

I am trying to create a function to replace some values from a given string, but I'm receiving the following error : `EOL while scanning single-quoted string.`

No sure what I am doing wrong:

```
 def DataClean(strToclean):
        cleanedString = strToclean
        cleanedString.strip()
        cleanedString=  cleanedString.replace("MMMM/", "").replace("/KKKK" ,"").replace("}","").replace(",","").replace("{","")
        cleanedString = cleanedString.replace("/TTTT","")
        if cleanedString[-1:] == "/":
           cleanedString = cleanedString[:-1]

        return str(cleanedString)
```

Comment: can you share the data you are feeding this function with?

Comment: Please provide the string that is input to this function so we can test what you're doing. Otherwise we can't help. Also, please provide the line in the code that produces the EOL error.

Comment: I am willing to bet that the error does not occur in a function that does not contain single quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that with a much simpler solution using the `regex` module. Define a pattern that will match any `MMM/` or `/TTT` and replace it with `''`.

```
import re

pattern = r'(MMM/)?(/TTT)?'

text = 'some text MMM/ and /TTT blabla'
re.sub(pattern, '', text)
# some text and blabla
```

In your function it would look like

```
import re

def DataClean(strToclean):
       clean_str = strToclean.strip()
       pattern = '(MMM/)?(KKKK)?'
       new_str = re.sub(pattern, '', text)
       return str(new_str.rstrip('/'))
```

The `rstrip` method will remove `/` at the end of the string, if there any. (remove the need for if).

Build the pattern with all the patterns you are searching in the string. Using `(pattern)?` you define the patterns as optional. You can state as many as you want.

It is more readable than concatenating string operations.

**Note** the `rstrip` method will remove *all the trailing slashes*, not just one. If you want to remove just the last char, you need an if statement:

```
if new_str[-1] == '/':
    new_str = new_str[:-1]
```

The if statement use index access to the string, -1 means last char. The assignment happens with slicing, up to the last char.

Comment: This does not do what OP is asking. It is better to help OP understand what is wrong with their code in addition to providing an alternative.

Comment: You don't need to wrap the output in a call to `str`: it's already a string. Also, `rstrip` will remove *all* trailing slashes, not just the last one. You should clarify OP's intent on that one.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you were correct, my code was wrong. I've fixed it now